# Can we get the attribute names themselves from Sheets importxml

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a list of the data attributes from a website using Google Sheets IMPORTXML function. To clarify, I want the *names* of the attributes themselves as well as their values, and I don't need the text of the table itself.

Trying the website: https://thesilphroad.com/catalog

A sample of the code I want to extract from is:

```
<div class="pokemonOption sighted" data-nests="1" data-raid-boss="0" data-obtainable="1" data-released="1" data-shiny-obtainable="1" data-shiny-released="1" data-shadow-available="" data-shadow-released="1" data-pokemon-slug="bulbasaur" style="background-image:url(https://assets.thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/1.png), radial-gradient(#a9f712, #2ecc71);"><span>#001</span></div>
```

The formula I'm using is:

```
=importxml("https://thesilphroad.com/catalog","//div[@class='pokemonOption sighted']/@*
```

and it returns all the values of the attributes in 1 column, eg:

| attributes |
| --- |
| pokemonOption sighted |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| Bulbasaur |
| etc... |

But what I need is the *names* as well, eg data-nests="1". Alternatively, what about just a list of the attributes of that , eg.

| attribute names |
| --- |
| class |
| data-nests |
| data-raid-boss |
| data-released |
| etc... |

Does someone know how to extract this into Sheets using IMPORTXML or another method?

Thanks!

Comment: The formula [already seems to display the second table](https://imgur.com/7J9xc0c.png), is this not what you want?

Comment: Oh shoot! Thanks for noting that Rafa. Somehow in editing I had put them in backwards! **I have now edited my question to switch them to what I meant.**  So given that clarification, is it possible to get the attribute names (class, data-nests, etc.) imported as well as or instead of the attribute values?

Comment: Ah, in which case I don't think this is possible, IMPORTXML gets just the values, it might be possible to extract them by means of [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) but honestly I don't even know if that would work.

Comment: Thanks @Rafa, I was hoping I was just missing something. Fingers crossed Sheets updates this function eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so sure, but I think `IMPORTXML` uses `XPath 1.0`.

To get all attributes, you need `XPath 2.0`.

You may want to create a custom formula with Google Apps Script.

```js
function pokemon(cell) {
  const url = 'https://thesilphroad.com/catalog';
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const content = response.getContentText();
  const results = content.match(/(<div class="pokemonOption sighted".+?<\/div>)/g)
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks! I'm not super experienced with Google Apps script so I'll have to experiment and get back to you. But that's very helpful as a workaround. Thanks!